# How do I organize data in alphabetical order?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

So I have some pieces of data stored in a folder as **.txt**, e.g. *FRED.txt* & *BOB.txt*, which in the text file contain their 5 random numbers chosen from 1 to 10 and I am stuck as to how I can print their names (in alphabetical order) along with their highest random number. I know that I have to use the *glob* or *os* libraries but I don't really know where to go with them.
So far I have this...

```
import glob, os
dataFile = open("directory_pathway", "r+")
dataFile.read() 
# Somehow printing names & highest number here.
dataFile.close()
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Use re to parse file names.

Comment: can you sample file content with output for FRED.txt & BOB.txt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get only text file from the input directory by `glob` module.
2. Use `for` loop to iterate every text file.
3. Read file content.
4. Get max number from the file content.
5. Add into result dictionary.
6. Sort dictionary keys and print values.

input: Following contents in `FRED.txt` file

```
2
4
6
8
10
```

code:

```
import glob
import os

dir_path = "/home/vivek/Desktop/stackoverflow/input"
text_files = glob.glob(dir_path+"/*.txt")
print "Test Files:", text_files

result = {}
for i in text_files:
    # Read file content.
    with open(i, 'rb') as fp:
        data = fp.read()
    max_no = max([int(j) for j in data.split()])
    result[os.path.basename(i)] = max_no

#- Sort and print File names.
sorted_file_names = sorted(result.keys())
for i in sorted_file_names:
    print "File Name: %s, MAx Random Number: %d"%(i, result[i])
```

output:

```
Test Files: ['/home/vivek/Desktop/stackoverflow/input/AOB.txt', '/home/vivek/Desktop/stackoverflow/input/ABO.txt', '/home/vivek/Desktop/stackoverflow/input/FRED.txt', '/home/vivek/Desktop/stackoverflow/input/BOB.txt']
File Name: ABO.txt, MAx Random Number: 9
File Name: AOB.txt, MAx Random Number: 9
File Name: BOB.txt, MAx Random Number: 9
File Name: FRED.txt, MAx Random Number: 10
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow/input$
```

Comment: Thank you Vivek Sable :D

Comment: Welcome, If you have any query  then  I can be reached anytime via email at vivekbsable@gmail.com, for my skype id: vivek.igp.

Comment: @F_anon If my answer is useful for you then accept and upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob, os, re

names = []

path = os.path.join('path_to_dir', '*.txt')

for filename in glob.glob(path):
    names.append(filename)

names.sort()

for filename in names:
    print(re.search(r'\w+.txt', filename).group(0))
    text = open(filename, 'r')
    data = text.read().split()
    print(max(data, key = int), '\n')
    text.close()

raw_input()
```

Comment: Basically, the names are first appended to a list an sorted in alphabetical order. Then they are parsed and the highest number is found.

Answer (score 0):

sort the file names found with `glob`, `map` the contents to int and print the filename `f` and the `max`:

```
import glob
import os 

path = "path/"
for f in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.txt"))):
    with open(os.path.join(path, f)) as fl:
        print("Filename: {}\nMax value: {}".format(f, max(map(int, fl))))
```

`map` returns a map object so we don't need to create a list to find the `max`, we  only store one line/value at a time.

Comment: change `import os os` to `import os`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
result_dict = {}
for i in sorted([i for i in os.listdir("/path/to/folder/") if i.endswith(".txt")]):
    f = open(i)
    a = f.readlines()
    num = sorted([int(j.strip()) for j in a])
    print num
    result_dict[i] = num[-1]

for i,j in sorted(result_dict.items(), key=lambda s: s[0]):
    print i,j
```

Answer (score -1):

`sorted(glob.glob("*.txt"))` will get you the list of filenames, sorted. Then iterate over that list, open each file, and print whatever you like.

Comment: That doesn't read the contents though, nor does that produce the highest number in the file. And it is `sorted()`, not `sort()`.